# Shouldn't there be an "anatomy" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-management, tags

It strikes me as one of the most fundamental topics imaginable on this site, but for whatever reason, there is no [anatomy](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatomy) tag.  Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: Could you name some example question where you think that this tag would fit on?

Comment: My most recent question:  What determines whether a belly button will be an innie or an outie?  Also, any questions about body parts, organs, features, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It would very much depend on the question.

Most of the questions that I can think of off the top of my head that would fit the anatomy tag would probably be a better fit on Biology.SE. For example, your question about what determines whether a bellybutton is inner or outer, I don't consider to be on topic for health. What health impact would there be from knowing this? That (to me) is the defining characteristic of a health question.

Comment: Belly buttons aren't a biological feature, they are created by doctors - i.e., health professionals.  I consider biology to be natural, whereas "health" involves human actions.  A biologist might not know what makes an innie or an outie, but a doctor definitely would.

Comment: If anatomy wasn't directly related to health, doctors and nurses wouldn't have to study anatomy.  But they **do** study it, because anatomy and health are inextricably intertwined.  My mom is an RN, and she has her old anatomy textbooks in her bookcase to this day.  Polydactyly?  Anatomy and health.  Superfluous nipples?  Anatomy and health.  Abnormal physiology in general?  Anatomy and health.

Comment: This answer from parenting.com suggests that outie belly buttons are the result of scar tissue and/or  a minor hernia, which clearly makes it a health issue:  "A. It has nothing to do with how the umbilical cord was cut or clamped, says Daniel McGee, M.D., a pediatrician at DeVos Children's Hospital in Grand Rapids. Most outies are nothing more than extra scar tissue. The rest are caused by an umbilical hernia, when the stomach muscles don't fuse together properly after the cord stump falls off, causing abdominal tissues to poke through."